# Inserting distinct value in one column and repeated value in other

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a database table with only 2 columns : TaskId & Email
When a user clicks some button,it inserts a value into the Table.I have written a stored procedure as follows:

```
  create proc spTaskPerformed
  @TaskId int,
  @Email varchar(100)
  as
  begin
  Insert into tblTaskPerformed values(@TaskId,@Email)
  end
```

But i want to insert the values only when the TaskId is distict for a particular Email.If i use the distict keyword for TaskId,it doesnt let me insert the same TaskId even when the Email is changed.Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the pairs to be unique, you should create a unique constraint on the values:

```
create unique index tblTaskPerformed_TaskId_Email on tblTaskPerformed(TaskId, Email);
```

This will prevent duplicates in the table.

If you don't want the stored procedure to generate an error, then you can use `try`/`catch` statements to catch such errors.

Comment: where do i add this? in the stored procedure?

Comment: @Mash . . . You just run this once to create the index for the table.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a an if statement that looks for existence of the taskid and email

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tblTaskPerformed WHERE TaskId = @TaskId AND Email =@Email)
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO tblTaskPerformed VALUES(@TaskId,@Email)

END
```

Comment: What does this do exactly? SELECT 1 FROM tblTaskPerformed WHERE TaskId = @TaskId AND Email =@Email -- gives me any out?